# Expo-location callback for watchPositionAsync never called

Tags: react-native, expo, geolocation

Here is my straightforward code for using Location.watchPositionAsync. I run this on iOS (all recent versions have the same behavior). The callback never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

```
    import * as Location from 'expo-location';
    const FOREGROUND_LOCATION_ACCURACY = Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation;
    this.foregroundSubscription = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
        {   
            // For better logs, we set the accuracy to the most sensitive option
            accuracy: FOREGROUND_LOCATION_ACCURACY,
            distanceInterval: 0,
            timeInterval: 1000,
        },
        (_location) => {
            console.log('got foreground location subscription update');
            this.setLocation(_location);
        },
    );
```